# How to import a Flutter package (plugin - with a native implementation) to the Flutter project as a Deferred Component?

Tags: flutter, plugins, package, components, deferred

To reduce the size of my app, I implemented a part of my project as a separate plugin and I aimed to import it into the project as a [Deferred components](https://docs.flutter.dev/perf/deferred-components) (like Play Feature Delivery). But since the deferred component can only import the dart code in the lib of the main project and, the dart code outside the lib cannot be imported into the project, Therefore I could not import the plugin I implemented as a deferred component. Is there any other way to do this?

If this is successful (if it is possible to import packages or plugins as deferred components), it will be possible to greatly reduce the initially apk size of flutter apps. Also, I read [#57617](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/57617) but I couldn't find a successful answer from it.

A rough idea of ​​the project structure

- main_project

  - android
  - assets
  - my_package
  - lib
  - pubspec.yaml

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?